# Reformat Cells with folder paths to put the file names on a separate Row

Tags: vba, excel

On an Excel sheet, Col A has many thousands of rows that are sorted and formatted like this:

```
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\fileA
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\fileB
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\fileC
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\fileD
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\fileE
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder4\Folder5\fileF
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder4\Folder5\fileG
```

and I'd like to convert to this:

```
C:\\Folder1\Folder2\
fileA
fileB

C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\
fileC
fileD
fileE

C:\\Folder1\Folder2\Folder4\Folder5\
fileF
fileG
```

etc.

I'd prefer to do it with VBA if possible.

Then, with that done, there will frequently be folders that have so many enclosed files that the list extends beyond one screen height, and so there's no indication of which folder the visible files belong to.  I'd like to extract the path of the last folder that scrolled off screen at the top, and maybe put it into a var that gets updated with the scroll, then I'll put that on a TextBox and leave it out for reference.

Ok, that last part looks hard, but full marks if you can help me get the first part done.

- Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. Since there is no event to capture when the user scrolls, the folder "header row" is repeated every 20 rows if necessary.

```
Sub ReformatCells()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lRowStart As Long
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFolderPrev As String
    Dim sFolderCur As String
    Const MAX_ROW_SECTION As Long = 20

    With ActiveSheet
        lRow = 0                  ' row before first row to format
        sPath = "start"           ' any non-zero-length string
        sFolderPrev = CStr(Timer) ' value guarenteed not to match
        Do While Len(sPath) > 0
            lRow = lRow + 1
            sPath = .Cells(lRow, 1).Value
            sFolderCur = GetFolder(sPath)
            If sFolderCur <> sFolderPrev Then
                ' new folder, so insert a blank row and "header row"
                .Rows(lRow).Insert
                .Rows(lRow).Insert
                lRow = lRow + 1
                lRowStart = lRow
                .Cells(lRow, 1) = sFolderCur
                sFolderPrev = sFolderCur
                lRow = lRow + 1
                .Cells(lRow, 1) = Mid$(sPath, Len(sFolderPrev) + 1)
            Else
                If lRow - lRowStart >= MAX_ROW_SECTION Then
                    ' repeat folder header
                    .Rows(lRow).Insert
                    .Cells(lRow, 1) = sFolderPrev & " (cont)"
                    lRowStart = lRow
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                End If
                ' just trim off the folder
                .Cells(lRow, 1) = Mid$(sPath, Len(sFolderPrev) + 1)
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
Function GetFolder(sPath As String) As String
    Dim iPos As Integer
    iPos = InStrRev(sPath, "\")
    If iPos > 0 Then
        GetFolder = Left$(sPath, iPos)
    Else
        GetFolder = sPath
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel, that works well. I tarted it up a little by changing the color and weight of the font for the rows with Folders, but other than that it works as is.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do the first part with a dictionary object and InStrRev. It'll create the sheet you want on Sheet2 and not mess with Sheet1. Since I stay away from inserting/deleting, this method is fast (**about 1.5 seconds for 3500+ rows**). You might want to add error checking in case you have rows that are not legal file paths.

**How it works:**

- Dump column into a varray to work with
- Find folder path using InStrRev on "\" and add path to dict as key and file as item
- If the path exists, I append the new file onto the last one and seperate with ", "
- On sheet 2, I loop through the dict and dump the data in the desired format.

Code:

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dim i As Long, j As Long, pathEnd As Long
Dim varray As Variant, folderName As Variant
Dim path As String, fileName As String, files() As String

With Sheets(1)
    varray = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With

For i = 1 To UBound(varray, 1)
    pathEnd = InStrRev(varray(i, 1), "\")
    path = Left$(varray(i, 1), pathEnd)
    fileName = Mid$(varray(i, 1), pathEnd + 1)
    If Not dict.exists(path) Then
        dict.Add path, fileName
    Else
        dict.Item(path) = dict.Item(path) & ", " & fileName
    End If
Next

i = 1
With Sheets(2)
    For Each folderName In dict
        .Range("A" & i).Value = folderName
        files = Split(dict.Item(folderName), ", ")
        For j = 0 To UBound(files)
            .Range("A" & i).Offset(j + 1, 0).Value = files(j)
        Next
        i = i + UBound(files) + 3
    Next
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Issun, I tried Rachel's solution first, and it worked so well I didn't go further.  But thanks for the reply.